# How can I serialize form state in Javascript/jQuery between AJAX requests?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I know how to serialize a form:

```
$("#attributeform").serialize()
```

but I want to store this in some kind of variable, like a hash, so that I can retrieve these values and resubmit them in order to transition between states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead. It produces an array where you can save and edit.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to use a simple hashtable for this. I didn't want to mess with serializeArray because I was actually looking not to hash the form values, but to hash the serialized form to ANOTHER value. Sorry if I wasn't clear.